# Rails redirect_to - I also want to the page to reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, reload

Turbolinks is running throughout the app. I need the page to reload in a certain scenario, inside a create method.

This redirects to the correct page, but does not reload the page:

`redirect_to convos_path`

---

This redirects to convos_path, but does not reload the page

```
redirect_to convos_path, data: { no_turbolink: true } and return
```

---

This doesn't do anything

`redirect_to convos_path, turbolinks: false and return`

I can see in the server logs it says

`Rendered convos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms)`

How can I do a redirect_to, and have the page reload when it goes there?

Answer (score 7):

Rails Turbolinks 5

Redirect and reload full page

```
redirect_to @convos_path, turbolinks: false
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution from [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/204).

```
<a data-turbolinks='false' href="url_here">Link Here</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution to the same problem was not related to turbolinks. Make sure your forms don't have `data-remote="true"` property.

[`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with), the [recommended](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25197) way since Rails 5.1, creates remote forms by default and you [have to pass `local: true` explicitly](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28764).

Answer (score -1):

redirect_back(fallback_location: fallback_location)